# Camel 2.16.0 missing components

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I upgraded my Fabric8 Spring Boot Camel pom.xml to use Camel 2.16.0 but not all components appear to be available in 2.16.0

I had to leave the following components at 2.15.3 as I get "Missing artifact" for the 2.16.0 versions:

- camel-metrics
- camel-jsonpath
- camel-spring-boot

Are these not available in Camel 2.16.0?

I'm using Fabric8 version 2.2.46 and Spring Boot version 1.2.6.RELEASE.

Comment: Yes all the JARs are in maven central, but as they were synced yesterday maybe there were some download troubles. Try again today. And the next fabric8 release is updated to Camel 2.16 out of the box.

Comment: I changed the Fabric8 version to 2.2.47 and I'm still seeing the same problem with these three jar files specifically. It's really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to delete my local Maven repository and rebuild.

Delete the artifacts (or the full local repo) from c:\Users\username.m2\repository by hand.